# Formatar nomes de cidades e ignorar palavras como "do", "dos", "das", "da", etc

Tags: php, string, variáveis, funções

Estou trabalhando com Webservice cujo nome das cidades estão todos desformatados e eu gostaria de criar uma função para tratar os nomes uniformemente. Um exemplo é este:

**PORTO DE GALINHAS**

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

**Porto de Galinhas**

Eu teria que dar um explode na ***string*** tratar todas as variáveis de uma só vez colocando tudo em minúsculo e logo após dar um `ucfirst` em cada palavra fazendo exceções de `ucfirst` em palavras pré-definidas como ***da, das, do, dos*** ...

Conheço o processo mas não sei colocar em execução.

Ensaiei alguma coisa:

```
$string = "PORTO DE GALINHAS";
$array = explode(' ', $string);

foreach ($array as $ar) {
    $dados = strtolower($ar);
    $dados .= "&nbsp;";

    // Imprime porto de galinhas
    $cidade = trim($dados);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Um esboço que pode ser facilmente adaptado:

```
function properCase( $string ) {    
   $ignorar = array( 'do', 'dos', 'da', 'das', 'de' );
   $array = explode(' ', strtolower( $string ) );
   $out = '';
   foreach ($array as $ar) {
      $out .= ( in_array ( $ar, $ignorar ) ? $ar : ucfirst( $ar ) ).' ';
   }
   return trim( $out );
}

echo properCase( 'PORTO DE GALINHAS' ).PHP_EOL;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/f5pRDh)**.

> **Importante:** se for usar com UTF-8, lembre-se de usar `mb_convert_case` no lugar das funções `ucwords` e `strtolower`, para que as letras com acentuação não fiquem com *case* errado.

Comment: Tá ai uma pergunta com respostas que podem ajudar muita gente :)

Comment: @MarcosVinicius isso é bom na hora de cadastrar as coisas no DB, só tem que tomar cuidado em algumas situações. Por exemplo, Rua XV de Novembro vai dar problema. Mas pra maioria dos casos, funciona. Se a pessoa pensar um pouco adapta fácil fácil a lógica para cuidar dos romanos (e por tudo em upper).

Comment: Tá blz, então não o que eu quis dizer é pra tirar o `strtolower` de dentro do `foreach`, assim: http://ideone.com/6zHiGe

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no fim, ja que era pra otimizar apelei :D

Comment: Vale um +100 :D

Comment: `properCase` é nome que só os filósofos dão as suas funções ;)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters espero que isso não seja ruim :P

Comment: Não, não é ruim. Eu gosto de lançar os nomes em inglês também, rsrsrsrs

Comment: Mas se o usuario colocar mais de um espaço?

Comment: @Luhhh Fica com mais de um espaço na saida ué (mas funciona da mesma maneira :) . A pergunta não pede para mudar os espaços. O código preserva conforme foi digitado.

Comment: @Luhhh se quiser remover espaços duplos, tem várias maneiras. pode usar replace, explode com array_filter, preg_replace, depende do que for conveniente para o seu código específico.

Answer (score 12):

Eu faria assim:

```
str_replace(array("De ", "Do ", "Dos ", "Da ", "Das "),
     array("de ", "do ", "dos ", "da ", "das "), ucwords(strtolower("PORTO DE GALINHAS")));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jL9xoO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iljemevi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/RemoveStopWord.php).

Documentação do [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php).

Documentação do [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Dá para melhorar a forma de tratar essas coisas. Essa é uma forma simplista de fazer o intento, mas é o que pede a pergunta.

Vendo os comentários espalhados vou fazer a versão da função que pode personalizar as exceções:

```
function capitalize($string, $search = array("De ", "Do ", "Dos ", "Da ", "Das "), $replace = array("de ", "do ", "dos ", "da ", "das ")) {
    return str_replace($search, $replace, ucwords(strtolower($string)));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ntC24O). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rsseniro-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/RemoveStopWord2.php).

Comment: Ah legal, bom exemplo +1

Comment: Essa função talvez tenha um problema ... e se dentre os itens do `array $search` tiver uma string ***DO***? Na função demonstrada, não vai tratar ... Por isso que eu acho que se faz o contrário ... verifica se existe a "palavra" em qualquer uma de suas formas "maiúsculo, minúsculo, misturado" e dá um `strtolower` nela. Pelo menos eu acho.

Comment: E porque teria uma `DO` no `$search`, basta não colocar. A função é flexível, se usar ela de um jeito, ela vai dar um resultado, se usar de outro, vai dar outro resultado. Se não quer esse outro, não use deste jeito. A única forma de evitar isto é tirar a flexibilidade. Acho que só piora a função, mas fique à vontade para tirar, é só tirar as variáveis e usar o literal fixo.

Comment: mb_convert_case não seria melhor por conta do utf-8?

Comment: Seria, mas nem todo mundo precisa de UTF-8. Aí seria *overkill*.

Answer (score 10):

Como alternativa, eu faria assim:

```
<?php
function formatarString($str, $glue = ' ')
{
    //torna minúscula e divide string por espaços, tabs e outros do meta-caractere \s (remove espaços desnecessários)
    $palavras = preg_split('#\s+#', strtolower($str));

    //Lista de palavras ignoradas
    $ignoreList = array('de', 'as', 'do', 'dos', 'da', 'das');

    foreach ($palavras as &$palavra) {
        if (in_array($palavra, $ignoreList) === false) {
            $palavra = ucfirst($palavra);
        }
    }

    return implode($glue, $palavras);
}
```

Para HTML pode usar assim:

```
echo formatarString('PORTO DE GALINHAS', '&nbsp;'); //Saída: Porto&nbsp;de&nbsp;Galinhas
```

Mas isto é opcional, o segundo parâmetro é o que terá entre as palavras, por padrão usa espaços

```
echo formatarString('PORTO DE GALINHAS'); //Saída: Porto de Galinhas
```

> **Nota:** para usar acentos use o `mb_convert_case($dados, MB_CASE_TITLE)`, isto precisará estar ativo no seu php.ini e/ou instalado via repositório (por exemplo `apt` no Debian), então ficaria assim:
>
> ```
> $palavras = preg_split('#\s+#', $str);
>
> //Lista de palavras ignoradas
> $ignoreList = array('de', 'as', 'do', 'dos', 'da', 'das');
>
> foreach ($palavras as &$palavra) {
>     if (in_array($palavra, $ignoreList) === false) {
>         $palavra = mb_convert_case($palavra, MB_CASE_TITLE);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note também que não defini o charset das strings, ele usa por padrão o valor retornado de `mb_internal_encoding()`, então se pretende usar outro codec ajuste antes de usar a função, assim:
>
> ```
> mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); //Se for usar utf-8
>
> echo formatarString('DECORAÇÃO DE AMBIENTES');
> ```

---

Exemplos de uso (teste online no repl.it: https://repl.it/@inphinit/de-do-da-com-ucwords):

```
$string = "PORTO DE GALINHAS";

echo "Original: $string\n";

$string = formatarString($string, ' ');

echo "Ajustado: $string\n";

echo "----------------\n";

$string = "DEMAIS AFAZERES";

echo "Original: $string\n";

$string = formatarString($string, ' ');

echo "Ajustado: $string\n";

echo "----------------\n";

$string = "OS DEMAIS AFAZERES";

echo "Original: $string\n";

$string = formatarString($string, ' ');

echo "Ajustado: $string\n";
```

Saída:

```
Original: PORTO DE GALINHAS
Ajustado: Porto de Galinhas
----------------
Original: DEMAIS AFAZERES
Ajustado: Demais Afazeres
----------------
Original: OS DEMAIS AFAZERES
Ajustado: Os Demais Afazeres
```

Comment: Está sem saída @Guilherme Nascimento ...

Comment: Como eu disse que precisava de uma função, provavelmente a resposta certa vai ser do Guilherme mas a do Bacco também está ótima.

Comment: Sim, eu sei ... essa adaptação eu consigo fazer. Obrigado vocês.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius acabei de editar o código, pra melhor performance acaso for usar com vários processos :)

Answer (score -3):

Gosto de usar expressões regulares para isso pela simplicidade que a mesma proporciona. A função preg_replace() fornece o que precisamos usando expressão regular.

```php
function nomeProprio($input) {
    return preg_replace('/\sd(\ws?)\s/i', ' d$1 ' , mb_convert_case($input, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8"));
}

$input = 'PORTO DE GALINHAS'; // texto vindo do webservice

echo nomeProprio($input);
```

(**veja funcionando aqui** [ideone](https://ideone.com/Vtg34i))

a primeira coisa que vai acontecer na string PORTO DE GALINHAS é que ela passará pela função mb_convert_case() que tem o parâmetro MB_CASE_TITLE e UTF-8 Que Servem Para Converter A String Em Case Title e o charset em UTF-8 respectivamente. Resultando em:

```
"Porto De Galinhas"
```

a expressão regular será utilizada nessa string

```
Dissecando a expressão regular: /\sd(\ws?)\s/i

/ // delimitador de início da expressão regular
\s // exige que haja um espaço
d // exige que haja a letra d
( // inicia um grupo de captura para ser utilizado na sequência -> $1
\w // que exige que tenha uma letra(\w), também poderia ser [aeiou]
s? // seguido ou não da letra s
) // finaliza o grupo de captura
\s // mais uma vez exige que haja outro espaço
/ // delimitador de fim da expressão regular
i // faz com que a expressão seja case insensitive considerando o d ou D
```

que encontrará " De ", fará a extração apenas da letra "e" e a colocará no grupo de captura $1 fazendo com que

```
" De "
```

seja substituido por

```
" de "
```

exibindo como resultado final:

```
"Porto de Galinhas"
```

como o \w pode ser qualquer letra encontraria também

```
" Da ", " Di ", " Do ", " Du ", " D(qualquer letra) "...
```

no caso acima apenas as vogais entram no grupo de captura. E também:

```
" Das ", " Dis ", " Dos ", " Dus ", " D(qualquer letra)s "...
```

nesse outro caso entram as vogais acompanhadas da letra s que serão colocadas no lugar de $1 resultando em:

```
" das ", " dis ", " dos ", " dus ", " d(qualquer letra)s "...
```

Repare que a substituição será apenas na parte " De " pois o restante já ficou correto com a utilização da função mb_convert_case.