# Pergunta simples sobre o comando title()

Tags: python, string

se eu colocar por exemplo o nome:

> roberto justo da silva

usando o `title` ele fica assim:

> Roberto Justo Da Silva

Como faço para que o comando `title` não modifique a palavra 'da' para ficar assim:

> Roberto Justo da Silva

Obviamente usei um exemplo simples mas gostaria de um modo que mudasse se tivesse os nomes em um arquivo `txt` e com vários sobrenomes onde o 'da' aparece em lugares diferentes.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma boa forma de se fazer isso é separando a sua string de entrada com um `split` por espaço, depois vai salvar isso em um `array de string`. Agora é só você comparar os elementos do array, quando o elemento for igual a `da ou de` não aplica o title nele `i=0
string_nome=input("Digite o nome:")
nome_dividido=string_nome.split(' ')
while(len(nome_dividido)>i):
    print(nome_dividido[i])
    if(nome_dividido[i] == 'da' or nome_dividido[i] == 'de'):
        nome_dividido[i]=nome_dividido[i]
    else:
        nome_dividido[i]=str.title(str(nome_dividido[i]))
    i=i+1
print(nome_dividido)`

O único problema é que precisara de transformar novamente esse array em string.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Não é um comando é um método e ele só pode ser aplicado em dados do tipo `string`. [Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.title). Ele é bem básico e não trata exceções, o que de fato diminui sua utilidade. Então você tem que criar algo manual que varra toda a `string` e modifique a caixa da letra de acordo com as regras que você estabelecer. Ou seja, tem que criar um algoritmo de *parse*. Se não ligar para a eficiência pode usar este método mas tratar essas palavras de uma forma um pouco diferente em outro passo. Já foi mostrado [como se faz em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105683/101). Lá dava para ajudar mais porque existia uma tentativa, aqui a pergunta é mais conceitual, por isso a resposta é mais conceitual.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Usando a ideia do amigo acima fiz uma função para te dar uma ideia para talvez resolver seu problema.

```
def newTitle(name):
    name=name.split(' ')
    exceptions=['da','de']
    titledName=''
    for i in name:
        if i in exceptions:
            titledName+=i
        else:
            titledName+=i.title()
        titledName+=' '
    return(titledName[:len(titledName)-1])
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Opa,

A resposta do nosso amigo Francis é muito boa, porém eu estava enfrentando problemas pois algumas substrings eu queria que ficasse sempre maiúscula. Logo, modifiquei o código e agora funciona perfeitamente em todos os casos.

```
def string_maiusculo(x):
    padroes_maiusculo = "ceo, cfo, pcb, pcp, dp, ti, rh, ii, i"#Strings que são obrigatoriamente maiúsculas
    excecoes=['da','de','do','a','e','o','em']#Strings que são obrigatoriamente minúsculas
    x = x.split(' ')#Separa a String pelos espaços em branco.
    titled_string=''
    for i in x:#Percorro a String toda.
        if i in excecoes:#Quando for excecao ignora.
            titled_string+=i
        elif i in padroes_maiusculo:#Quando for predefinido como maiusculo faz o tratamento.
            titled_string+=i.upper()
        else:#Deixa apena a primeira letra em maiusculo
            titled_string+=i.title()
        titled_string+=' '
    return(titled_string[:len(titled_string)-1])
```

Caso não tenha substrings que queiram deixar maiúsculas é só deixar "padores_maiusculo" em branco.